# Frida manipulating arguments - Android

Tags: android, java, javascript, apk

I've attempting to learn how to use Frida to instrument android app, just for person interest.

So far I've managed to get my environment set up with a physical android tablet and I can successfully run the [example](http://www.frida.re/docs/examples/android/) on Frida's website. In addition to changing variables in the method I want to change the arugment passed to the method. I know how to do this with Xposed but I'm not sure with Frida.

**Generic Question:** How can the arugments passed to method be maniputed with Frida and what is good souce of documentation and examples for Frida?

---

**More specific question:**

I wanted something that was more of a challenge so I moved onto Snapchat. My aim is to emulate the speed spoofing feature of the [SnapPrefs](https://github.com/marzika/Snapprefs) Xposed module as this seemed fairly simple to do and its effect can be easily seen in the app. I looked through the SnapPrefs souce and found that I need to hook the "adL" class and change the argument passed to the "a" method.

The code for the method in the APK is:

`public final void a(float paramFloat)
  {
      ....
  }`

I'm using this JavaScript code in order to print "Speed showing" to the screen whenever the method is active.

```
Java.perform(function () {
// Function to hook is defined here
var SpeedometerView = Java.use('adL');

// Whenever button is clicked
SpeedometerView.a.overload('float').implementation = function (v) {
    // Show a message to know that the function got called
    send('Speed showing');

    // Call the original onClick handler
    this.a.overload('float');
};
});
```

So from this: What would be the easiest way to manipulate the paramFloat argument?

Answer (score 2):

If I understand your question correctly, you want to change the parameter, `v`, inside the inner function. Right? 
If that's the case, you would already have access to the `v` argument inside your inner function. So what you can do is something like this:

```
Java.perform(function () {
// Function to hook is defined here
var SpeedometerView = Java.use('adL');

// Whenever button is clicked
SpeedometerView.a.overload('float').implementation = function (v) {
    // Show a message to know that the function got called
    send('Speed showing');
    old_param_value = v;
    new_param_value = 100.00;
    // Call the original onClick handler
    x = this.a(new_param_value);
};
});
```

also, assuming you wanted to change the value of the param from whatever exiting to 100.00
return x if needed.

However, if you are looking to do this dynamically, like say based on user input etc., at run time, I do not know how to do it. In fact, I would be keeping an eye out for it if someone answers that !

In fact I tried things like this:

`s4.js`

```
Java.perform(
 function()
 {
   var item = Java.use("java.util.Random");
   console.log("Found random loaded");
   item.nextInt.overload("int").implementation = function(a)
   {
     var ret = this.nextInt(a);
     send("[*] The random no " + ret.toString());
     recv(function (received_json_object) {
           cheat_num = received_json_object.my_data
           console.log("[*] Cheated bot number received " + cheat_num);            
       }).wait();
     return cheat_num;
   }
 }
);
```

`not_working.py`

```
import time
import frida

def my_message_handler(message, payload):
   print message.get('payload')

   if message["type"] == "send":
       print "in here"      
       place_bot_chic_at = raw_input("Give the index where bot chicken should be placed ")
       print "bot chick will be placed at " + str(place_bot_chic_at)
       # script.post({"my_data": 7331}) # This works perfectly fine.
       script.post({"my_data": place_bot_chic_at}) # This gives error as :
       print "Bot chick position sent"

device = frida.get_device_manager().enumerate_devices()[-1]
pid = device.spawn(["chicken.wars.main"])
device.resume(pid)
time.sleep(1)  
session = device.attach(pid)
with open("s4.js") as f:
   jss = f.read()
   script = session.create_script(jss)

script.on("message", my_message_handler) #register the message handler
script.load()
raw_input()
```

But when I run that python, I get the following error:

```
lib/python2.7/site-packages/frida/core.py", line 298, in _on_message
  callback(message, data)
File "not_working.py", line 12, in my_message_handler
  script.post({"my_data": place_bot_chic_at}) # This gives error as :
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'post'
```

Also, strangely, the moment after the `in here` string gets printed, I was expecting the user input line to be executed next. But that does not happen unless I press an enter. As soon as I press enter, the user input line `place_bot_chic_at = raw_input("Give the index where bot chicken should be placed ")` gets executed. I give a value and enter and that's when the above error occurs. 
I have no idea what is going wrong. If someone does, please help understand where am I going wrong.